# How to speed up my code for comparing four lists in python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have four lists that are the same length:

```
a=[a1,a2,a3,...,an]
b=[b1,b2,b3,...,bn]
c=[c1,c2,c3,...,cn]
d=[d1,d2,d3,...,dn]
```

What I want to do is:

```
lengh=len(a)
s=[]
for i in range(0,lengh):
    if a[i]>b[i] and a[i]>c[i]:
        s.append(a[i]+0.5*b[i]+0.25*d[i])
    elif b[i]>a[i] and b[i]>c[i]:
        s.append(b[i]+0.5*a[i]+0.25*d[i])
    else:
        s.append(c[i]+0.25*d[i])
```

This worked, but `len(a)>30000000` and it is too slow. What can I do to speed up this code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop is horrendously inefficient, and using lists with numpy is similarly bad form.

To me, the answer rests on using `numpy.choose()` which will take an index array (which will be 0,1,2 based on which part of your `if` statement above applies to a given index) and a series of numpy arrays where you will compute each of the `if` calculations above.

So, assuming your turn your lists into numpy arrays, something like:

```
choice1 = a+0.5*b+0.25*d
choice2 = b+0.5*a+0.25*d
choice3 = c+0.25*d
```

Then,

```
opt1 = np.greater(a,np.max(b,c))*1
opt2 = np.greater(b,np.max(a,c))*2
opt3 = np.greater(c,np.max(a,b))*3
ind = np.max(opt1,np.max(opt2,opt3))-1
s = np.choose(ind,choice1,choice2,choice3)
```

Numpy is fast processing the arrays, so although this looks like lots of wasted effort you are avoiding the `for` loop overhead which will be a huge win for the large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with *numpy* and *pandas* even though you only have Python lists. So you hint at how to speed this up.

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

# function that takes Numpy arrays    
def compute_result(a, b, c, d):
    s1 = ne.evaluate('a + 0.5*b + 0.25*d')
    s2 = ne.evaluate('b + 0.5*a + 0.25*d')
    s3 = ne.evaluate('c + 0.25*d')
    s = np.where((a>b)&(a>c), s1, np.where((b>a)&(b>c), s2, s3))
    return s
```

So now to check the performance:

```
length = 30000000
a = np.random.rand(length)
b = np.random.rand(length)
c = np.random.rand(length)
d = np.random.rand(length)
```

And then in iPython:

```
In [35]: %timeit compute_result(a, b, c, d)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.31 s per loop
```